# angularjs: mouse-hover text not appearing on mouse (x,y) location

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written a code in angular-js for mouse-hover text. I need the hover text to appear in the position where the mouse pointer is located.
But unfortunately its not happening. The hover-text is remaining fixed in a particular location, and google-Chrome developer tool shows error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`
Even though I have specified the `id` in `div` tag, its not detecting the `id` property.

Here is the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var tooltipSpan = document.getElementById("demo");

    window.onmouseover = function (e) {
    var x = e.clientX,
        y = e.clientY;
    tooltipSpan.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
    tooltipSpan.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
};
    </script>

</head>
<body ng-app="">

    <div id="demo" ng-init="tooltip=false" ng-show="tooltip" style="border: 1px solid black;width: 230px;height: 40px;background-color: gray;color: white;z-index: 1;position: fixed;">Hi..Welcome In Angular JS World.</div>


    <table border=1>
    <tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th></tr>
    <tr><td ng-mouseover="tooltip=true" ng-mouseleave="tooltip=false">data 1</td>  <td>data 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>data 1</td>   <td ng-mouseover="tooltip=true" ng-mouseleave="tooltip=false">data 2</td></tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have your javascript loading before your html, `document.getElementById("demo")` ends up being null, since the DOM hasn't loaded yet.

Try moving that javascript to the bottom (I put it after the body tag, but not sure this is best practice). This way the DOM loads first, and then your javascript knows where to find the id of "demo".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `var tooltipSpan = document.getElementById("demo");` is being executed before the page has finished loading - therefore the variable `tooltipSpan` is `null`

I have modified your example to set `tooltipSpan` once the body has loaded

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>



      var tooltipSpan;

    function setTooltip() {
      tooltipSpan = document.getElementById("demo");
    }

    window.onmousemove = function (e) {
      if (!tooltipSpan) return;
    var x = e.clientX,
        y = e.clientY;
    tooltipSpan.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
    tooltipSpan.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
};
    </script>

</head>
<body ng-app="" onload='setTooltip()'>

    <div id="demo" ng-init="tooltip=false" ng-show="tooltip" style="border: 1px solid black;width: 230px;height: 40px;background-color: gray;color: white;z-index: 1;position: fixed;">Hi..Welcome In Angular JS World.</div>


    <table border=1>
    <tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th></tr>
    <tr><td ng-mouseover="tooltip=true" ng-mouseleave="tooltip=false">data 1</td>  <td>data 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>data 1</td>   <td ng-mouseover="tooltip=true" ng-mouseleave="tooltip=false">data 2</td></tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. the error was gone by your suggestion but the hover text still remained fixed. As @sainid mentioned, i moved the <script> after the body tag. it worked